# How to provide SSL Server certificate/ Client Certificate/ SSL Keys in Pyspark JDBC connection.. Trying to connect PostgreSQL in GCP from on Prem

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect from on prem pyspark to GCP PostgreSQL, how to provide the required certificates and syntax in Pyspark to connect GCP PostgreSQL

```
df2=spark.read.format('jdbc')\
              .option('driver','org.postgresql.Driver')\
              .option('url','XXXXXX')\
              .option("dbtable",'XXXXXX')\
              .option('user','XXXXX')\
              .option('password','XXXXXX')\
              .option('ssl',True)\
              .option('sslmode','require')\
              .load()
```

I am getting this error -

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
```

Comment: Have you downloaded server CA certificate and client certificate in your onprem server from GCP? If yes, then you need to set `sslrootcert` and `sslcert` options in the current code and provide the respective file paths for server CA certificate and client certificate

Comment: Yes, I have the server_cert.pem / client_cert.pem / psql_client.pk8.. But I am not sure, how to use them in pyspark connection syntax.. Can you please help me with right syntax to specify the certificates..

Comment: Try adding `.option('sslrootcert','<path_to_server_ca_certificate>')` and 
`.option('sslcert','<path_to_client_certificate>')` before calling `load()` method. Hopefully this should work.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'm adding it to the answer as well, please accept it to close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `sslrootcert` and `sslcert` options in your existing to resolve the issue. See the below implementation for details -

```
df2=spark.read.format('jdbc')\
              .option('driver','org.postgresql.Driver')\
              .option('url','jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>')\
              .option('url','XXXXXX')\
              .option("dbtable",'XXXXXX')\
              .option('user','XXXXX')\
              .option('password','XXXXXX')\
              .option('ssl',True)\
              .option('sslmode','require')\
              .option('sslrootcert','<path_to_server_ca_certificate>')\
              .option('sslcert','<path_to_client_certificate>')\
              .option('sslkey', '<path_to_client_key>')
              .load()
```

Comment: I was not able to vote, as I am new user..

Comment: we may need include sslkey in options.. can you please update the solution, Dipanjan..

Comment: You can just add this `.option('sslkey', '<PATH_TO_CLIENT_KEY>')` in the above code before calling `.load()`

Comment: yes Dipanjan.. that right.. for the sake of others, I am just asking to update the solution..

Comment: Done! Upvote too if you like :)

Comment: I have got the upvote capability..